# Return the index of a particular value in an array of integers

Tags: java, arrays

> Write a method named indexOf that returns the index of a particular value in an array of integers. The method should return the index of the first occurrence of the target value in the array. If the value is not in the array, it should return -1. For example, if an array called list stores the following values:
>
> `int[] list = {42, 7, -9, 14, 8, 39, 42, 8, 19, 0};`
>
> Then the call `indexOf(list, 8)` should return 4 because the index of the first occurrence of value 8 in the array is at index 4. The call `indexOf(list, 2)` should return -1 because value 2 is not in the array.

My attempt doesn't work when the answer need to be -1.

```
 public int indexOf(int[] arr,int value) {
        int k=0;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(arr[i]==value){
                k=i;
                break;
            }
        }
    return k;
}
```

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: `arr.indexOf(value)` will do the trick

Answer (score 4):

Initialise `k` to `-1` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the value of k to -1 so that if the number doesn't exists in the array it will return -1.

```
int k=-1;
```